Load switch with back to back P-MOSFET has problem
We were trying to make load switch which will be placed between battery and motors for robot.
So we made some PCB which follows circuit on image.
When we tried this circuit it worked pretty well at first few times but after that MOSFET went wrong (source, gate and drain of MOSFET shorted) which especially the behind one (U8).
To solve this problem we tested again two more times

without C12 (failed)
without front MOSFET (U7) and connecting wire between source and drain of front MOSFET

After these test we searched some document and considering about flyback diode.
Will this fly back diode can be a solution of this problem? or is there any other problem?
edited)

Front MOSFET means U7, and behind MOSFET means U8.
Yes I simulated using pspice there was no problem on pspice simulation and also check SOA.
Cause of my awful English skill there were miscommunications. At first time I though there is problem on C12 so I removed and tested but MOSFET (U8) was broken.
I want to check load switch without reverse MOSFET (U7) to figure out where is a problem. I removed U7 and wired drain and source of U7. On this test U8 was failed.
I apologize about ambiguous notation.



I don't know what a front or behind MOSFET is so use the circuit reference numbers please. Please also explain why you felt it necessary to choose a bidirectional switch configuration.

Have you simulated the turn-on transient? What was the voltage drop, current flow, and power dissipation? How does the waveform compare with the datasheet SOA curve?

Responding to OP:  without C12 (failed)  Does this mean that C12 failed, or did the experiment with C12 removed "fail"?  Please explain further, including what you mean by "failed".

Responding to OP: but after that MOSFET went wrong (Source Gate and Drain of MOSFET shorted).  Which MOSFET failed, was it U7, U8, or M2?

Responding to OP: without front MOSFET and connecting wire between Soure and Drain of front MOSFET.  What is the "front MOSFET", is it: U7, U8, or M2?

What is the purpose of C9?  It creates a long time constant the leads to significant heating in the FETs because they turn on so slowly.  Are the FETs mounted on heatsinks?

OTOH, the turn-off time is long enough that you might not see any benefit from adding a suppression diode to the output.

Is this a school project, a commercial product, or something else?


What is the purpose of C9? It creates a long time constant the leads to significant heating in the FETs because they turn on so slowly. Are the FETs mounted on heatsinks?


Purpose of C9 is for turning on slowly of MOSFETs.  And they are SMD typed parts. So, they are cooled by PCB's copper polygon.


OTOH, the turn-off time is long enough that you might not see any benefit from adding a suppression diode to the output.


Ok


Is this a school project, a commercial product, or something else?


It's kind of school project.


The reason of turning on slowly of MOSFETs is to prevent inrush current caused by load capacitor C10.

Here is your circuit, reworked for only one pass transistor.  Changing your R12 to a zener diode assures that the FET will be stay fully enhanced even if the +48 V source sags to a lower voltage.
D1-R1-C1 form a switch debounce network.  This prevents the power switch Q2 from flickering on and off rapidly when a switch is opened or closed.
Q2 will turn off more rapidly than in your circuit, so I added D3 to suppress motor transients.


Thank you for your Answer!
But i forgot to write down the purpose of back to back MOSFET.
They are used to prevent reverse current. Single MOSFET has a problem of reverse current by parasitic diode in MOSFET. So i need to use back to back MOSFETs.

What is the source of the reverse current?

Load resistance R11 is equivalent resistance of motor which is soure or reverser current. Sorry for lack of explation.

What is the nominal current when the motor is running?

I'm not sure about exact value but max current will be 20A.
